# How can I make the Vue component's class binding bind onto the inner element instead of the root element?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Suppose I have a very simple component that looks like this

```js
Vue.component("my-component", {
  template: `
    <p class="foo bar">
      <span>Hi</span>
    </p>
  `,
});
```

If I use the component like this

```html
<my-component class="baz boo"></my-component>
```

Final rendered HTML will look like this

```html
<p class="foo bar baz boo">
  <span>Hi</span>
</p>
```

**However, I want to bind my class onto the `<span>` tag instead of the root element.**

This is the result I want

```html
<p class="foo bar">
  <span class="baz boo">Hi</span>
</p>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, you can pass it as props.

```
<my-component :className="baz booz" />
```

inside that component

```
<span :class="class-name"> Hi </span>
```

Comment: `:class="className"` also need to declare props in `my-component`. `props: ['className']`.